# How do I stack DIV elements on top of each other with position: relative

Tags: html, css, position

I'm having a problem getting `div` elements to stack on top of each other vertically. I have a `mainwrapper` and 2 `div` elements inside them that I need to be stacked. But whenever I give the first inner `div` `position: absolute` and then `right: 0` or even `float: right`, it goes into the second `div`. Is there any way around this?

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="test1"></div>

    <div class="test2">
        <div class="test3"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 605px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 240px;
}

.test1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.test2 {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

.test3 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRV6L/).

Comment: Absolutely positioned elements will ignore other elements. You can't naturally stack them. You could make them "appear" to stack by explicitly defining their position. But if you want the elements to "respect" other elements, you might be better off redesigning without absolute positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would http://jsfiddle.net/uFf9D/ work?

I commented out the dimensions on .wrapper and added overflow: hidden. Then changed .test1 and .test2 to position: relative and float: right.

**Edit**: Readded the width since it's needed for centering.

```
.wrapper {
  width: 605px;
/*
  height: 240px;
*/
  overflow: hidden;
  ...
}

.test1 {
/*
  position: relative;
*/
  float: right;
  ...
}

.test2 {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  ...
}
```

If you want to skip the floats and overflow: hidden, direction: rtl might be a possible solution on .wrapper.. don't know if it works or whether it's inherited.

Try out this addition to .test2 to fill up .test1:

```
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
```

Comment: is it bad practice to use overflow: auto or overflow:hidden on DIV elements like your example?

Comment: I doubt it.. I've seen overflow:hidden suggested in many places for a container to cover floated elements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why you were positioning those like you were. I'm going to assume you were using position: absolute so that those divs wouldn't intervene with other content. Also, there's no need to put 'display: block' for divs, that's their default value.

Here's a fiddle that does as you pleased, and the wrapper is set to position: absolute so that those divs don't intervene with other content. Basically, you'd use the wrapper as a frame. 
[Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/wRV6L/1/)

```
.wrapper {
    width: 605px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -302.5px;
    position: absolute; 
    background: transparent;
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 240px;
}

.test1 {
    border: 2px solid green;
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
}

.test2 {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.test3 {
    border: 2px solid black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 0;
}
```

Note:

1. position: relative can do the same stuff as position: absolute, AND
   things still flow as if the element was still in its default
   position (but it doesn't have to be).
2. position: absolute takes that
   element out of the flow
3. position: fixed is the same as absolute but
   with reference to the window itself (think fixed navigation bars)

Comment: Accidentally pasted the original code instead of the new one, post is updated now.