# Flexbox with Picture and Overlapping Object

Tags: html, css

I try to put an image and overlapping objects side by side. And then when device width is smaller enough, it puts the image on top of overlapping objects. In this case the overlapping objects are search input (with completion capability that we don't want to discuss here).

So far I got this [my jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/ethereal1m/cwurw36v/1/)

my css code:

```
#banner-wrapper {
    order: 1;
     height: 70.7833px;
     width:40px;
     margin-left: 5%;
}
img {
    width: 40%;
}

@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
    #banner-wrapper {
        flex: 2 1 auto;
    }
    #peoplefind-sidebar {
        flex: 2 1 auto;
    }
}

@media all and (min-width: 360px) {
    #banner-wrapper, #banner-wrapper>* {
        order: 1;
    }
    #peoplefind-sidebar,#peoplefind-sidebar > *,.people-search   {
        order: 2;
    }
}

#header-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

#peoplefind-sidebar {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.people-search {
    top: 50%;
    height: 35%;
    width: 22% !important;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    position: absolute;
}

#peoplefind-input {
        background: transparent;
        z-index: 1;
}

#peoplefind-input-x {
        color: #CCC; background: transparent; 
}

#side-peoplefind-submit {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%;
    height: 30%;
    left: 80%;
}
```

its html counterpart:

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
    <div id="banner-wrapper">
        <img class="nav-logo-image" id="logo-img" src="http://images.freeimages.com/images/previews/ba3/sunflowers-3-1393952.jpg" alt="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="peoplefind-sidebar">
        <form id="peoplefind-form" action="peoplefind/profile" method="post">
            <input autocomplete="off" id="peoplefind-input" class="people-search" placeholder="Find contacts, item_id, and word search here" name="people_search"  type="text">
            <input id="peoplefind-input-x" class="people-search" name="people_search" disabled="disabled"  type="text">
            <button id="side-peoplefind-submit" type="submit">Find</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This one still doesn't work. As we decrease the size of the window to small size, it doesn't put the image on the top of the overlapping object.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are did with responsive. Because of this media css it's happend. 
#banner-wrapper {
    height: 70.7833px;
    margin-left: 5%;
    order: 1;
    width: 40px;
}

Comment: @Ezhil-UI Developer, could you be more clear? I'm not sure what are you suggesting.

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/cwurw36v/3/

Comment: @Michael_B, you got the row wrapping working but the overlapping objects not. The #peoplefind-input should overlap and position exactly on top of #peoplefind-input-x (as it is displayed on my code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot going on in your code, and I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to accomplish, but based on your question and comments it seems you're trying to resolve two issues:

1. *Make the `#peoplefind-sidebar` container wrap under the `#banner-wrapper` on smaller screens.*

   With a few adjustments to your CSS the containers will stack vertically on smaller screens. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cwurw36v/3/
2. *Make `#peoplefind-input` overlay `#peoplefind-input-x` on smaller screens.*

   You want an `input` to perfectly overlap another `input`. There are a lot of unknown variables for this request, like *when* and *where* do you want them to overlap. Below I've listed several posts with generic solutions.

   - [How to overlay one div over another div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2941189/3597276)
   - [CSS: How to position two elements on top of each other, without specifying a height?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6780614/3597276)
   - [How do I stack DIV elements on top of each other with position: relative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24226035/3597276)

---

UPDATE (based on comments)

> I try to put an image and overlapping objects side by side. And then
>   when device width is smaller enough, it puts the image on top of
>   overlapping objects.

Okay, I think this does it: http://jsfiddle.net/cwurw36v/4/

Comment: Hi Mike, for no 2, the overlay should happen always. If you look at my jsfiddle link, you only see 1 input rectangle. This is because one is overlapping thus your no 1 answer would have been correct if there is 1 rectangle input visible.  I think my question is irrelevant because you cannot wrap objects with relative and absolute position in flexbox. Am I right?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand your question now. But there are still many unknown variables. Forgetting that, I've created a basic layout that I believe does what you want. I hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/cwurw36v/4/

Comment: Ok, this is what I wanted. Kudos to your effort